# php check if function is available with array as source

Tags: php, function

I´m trying to check if several php functions are available. Source should be an array with function names. Unfortunately this seems not to work. I always get a negative return:

```
// Array with function names
$func_array = array("die",
                    "echo", "empty", "exit", "eval",
                    "include", "include_once", "isset",
                    "list",
                    "print",
                    "require", "require_once",
                    "unset","exec"
                    );

// Check Function
function func_avail($funcav) {   
    if ( function_exists($funcav) ) {
        echo "$funcav is enabled<br/>";
    }
    else {
        echo "$funcav is not enabled<br/>";
    }

}

// Loop through array
for ( $x = 0; $x < count ( $func_array ); $x++ )
{
        func_avail($func_array[$x]);
}
```

Question 1: Why does this not work? (Ouput is always not enabled)

Question 2: Does not enabled (function_exists = 0) means that the function was disabled within php.ini or could this also mean it is not available with this php version. F.E. I´m trying to use a function which is only available with a newer php Version.

Kind regards and, thanks!

Toni

Comment: Not all of those are functions. Some are language-level syntax constructs or pseudo functions.

Comment: Just check the version number

Comment: Here is a list of language constructs which you might mistake for functions : http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Comment: As @mario indicated, some are language-level syntax constructors. `exec()` in your example is enabled. Also try for example `imagettftext()` it will most likely return `enabled`.

Comment: Couldn't you do a `foreach()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question 1:** Why does this not work? Ouput is always *not enabled*

... except for `exec()`. Which is correct: none of the other items are functions, they are language constructs. (As far as I know, there's no way to disable a language construct.)

The manual page for [function_exists()](http://php.net/function_exists) confirms that:

> This function will return `FALSE` for constructs, such as `include_once` and `echo`.

> **Question 2:** Does not enabled (function_exists = 0) means that the
>   function was disabled within php.ini or could this also mean it is not
>   available with this php version. F.E. I´m trying to use a function
>   which is only available with a newer php Version.

It means exactly what [the manual says](http://php.net/function_exists):

> Checks the list of defined functions, both built-in (internal) and user-defined, for function_name.
>
> Note: A function name may exist even if the function itself is unusable due to configuration or compiling options (with the image functions being an example).

Comment: Hi Alvaro, okay I think I understand. function_exists does only check for real php functions thus all others are laguage constructs my output her is not enabled. my idea behind this is to get all used php function within an app with phpxref and in case of an server or better php update check if everything needed is still available.

Comment: That's not reliable. Your program might use a function argument that was added later.

Comment: true … I have to think again about solving php version problems. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [PHP_CompatInfo](http://bartlett.laurent-laville.org/), just in case.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, great tool thank you. I also tried this -> http://www.axel-hahn.de/axel/page_compi/php_deprecated.htm. Which seems to come from the other side, PHP_CompatInfo tells me which min PHP Version I need PHP_depreceated scans my files and warns me for depreceated used functions.